# Eclipse 4. Product dependencies vs plugin dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am new to eclipse (trying to do an eclipse rcp application) and there are a lot of things I don't understand.
One of them is the relationship (if there is one) between plugin dependencies (specified in the manifest as I understand) and product dependencies(specified in the product file).
From my point of view the product must depend on the plugin and transitively on all of the plugin dependencies (maven way) but it's not so simple of course.
Could someone explain those concepts(or if you know a good link throw it here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product dependencies defines which plugins will available at runtime and included in the product-export/build.

The dependencies which defined in the MANIFEST.MF are required to resolve this bundle.

For example: You have Bundle_A, Bundle_B and Bundle_C. Bundle_A has a dependency to Bundle_B.
Bundle_C has no requirements, but just extends Bundle_A with Extension Points (it's like optional).

If you add Bundle_A in the product and press "Add required Plug-ins" Bundle_B will follow. Because it's required to resolve it. Bundle_C is not required and will just available in your application, when you add it itself.

Hope anyone can confirm this.

Edit: You can find under [Eclipse Juno Help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp) -> Plugin-in Development Enviroment -> Concepts -> product" some additional information